# How to highlight search terms without plugin

Tags: search

How can I get the search terms highlighted without plugin?

Answer (score 17):

Add these 2 functions to your functions.php

```
function search_excerpt_highlight() {
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    $excerpt = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-highlight">\0</strong>', $excerpt);

    echo '<p>' . $excerpt . '</p>';
}

function search_title_highlight() {
    $title = get_the_title();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    $title = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-highlight">\0</strong>', $title);

    echo $title;
}
```

#### Edit:

To use the_content for your search results use the function below:

```
function search_content_highlight() {
        $content = get_the_content();
        $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
        $content = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-highlight">\0</strong>', $content);

        echo '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
    }
```

In your loop or search.php file call `<?php search_title_highlight(); ?>` instead of `<?php the_title(); ?>` and use `<?php search_excerpt_highlight(); ?>` instead of `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

In your css add the search-highlight class which will highlight all searched words in yellow.

```
.search-highlight {
    background:#FFFF00  
    }
```

Comment: Apply [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to `$keys` to prevent your regex from blowing up in case of special characters like parentheses or brackets.

Comment: What about highlighting the search term after the user clicks on the single and goes inside the post? Then the **get_search_query()** returns an empty string

Comment: Those should be filters for `the_excerpt` and `the_content` instead. Anyway: Nice answer, but the comment from @Geert could be worked in :)

Comment: It apply <strong class="search-highlight"> code in our readmore link also if it have search term,
How can we solve that.

Comment: it is replacing the  text in the readmore href also? how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The above works well I've run the similar code, but tie the title and excerpt together. But found it breaks when someone enters a space " " either at the beginning or end of a search query term.

So Ive add this line:

```
$keys = array_filter($keys);
```

```
// Add Bold to searched term
function highlight_results($text){
     if(is_search() && !is_admin()){
     $sr = get_query_var('s');
     $keys = explode(" ",$sr);
     $keys = array_filter($keys);
     $text = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', ''.$sr.'', $text);
     }
     return $text;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'highlight_results');
add_filter('the_title', 'highlight_results');
```

Hope this proves to help others.

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions break the page if the search term appears inside HTML tags.  You should use something like:

```
      $regEx = '\'(?!((<.*?)|(<a.*?)))(\b'. implode('|', $keys) . '\b)(?!(([^<>]*?)>)|([^>]*?</a>))\'iu';
      $text = preg_replace($regEx, '<strong class="search-highlight">\0</strong>', $text);
```

Comment: thanxs mate you made my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Combined 2 answers to use filters :

```
// Add class to searched terms
function highlight_results($text) {
    if (is_search() && !is_admin()) {
        $sr = get_query_var('s');
        $keys = explode(' ', $sr);
        $keys = array_filter($keys);
        $text = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', '<span class="search-highlight">\0</span>', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'highlight_results');
add_filter('the_title', 'highlight_results');
```

Then in your CSS (for example) :

```
.search-highlight {
    background: #ffff94;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```