# Search results highlight breaks my read more link

Tags: permalinks, search, read-more

I am attempting to add highlighting to my search results in the theme that I am coding.  I found the way to do it on this thread: [How to highlight search terms without plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16070/how-to-highlight-search-terms-without-plugin) and it worked wonderfully.  However, it is conflicting with my read more link whenever a permalink contains the search term by trying to do the replacement in the read more link causing the link to break oddly.

Does anyone have a suggestion or fix for it?

The following codes I use are as follows:

```
function search_excerpt_highlight() {
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    $excerpt = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<ins class="search-highlight">\0</ins>', $excerpt);
    echo '<p>' . $excerpt . '</p>';
}

function supralegal_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '&hellip;' . supralegal_read_more_link();
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'supralegal_auto_excerpt_more' );

function supralegal_read_more_link() {
    return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="read_more">' . __( 'Read more', 'supralegal' ) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function search_excerpt_highlight() {
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    $excerpt = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<ins class="search-highlight">\0</ins>', $excerpt);
    echo '<p>' . $excerpt . '&hellip;' . supralegal_read_more_link() . '</p>';
}

function supralegal_auto_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'supralegal_auto_excerpt_more' );

function supralegal_read_more_link() {
    return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="read_more">' . __( 'Read more', 'supralegal' ) . '</a>';
}
```