# Excerpt being limited too early

Tags: excerpt, content, limit

I grabbed the code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70913/how-can-i-limit-the-character-length-in-excerpt)

I have this in my post right now:

"Test sentence for excerpt purposes.

Link:

https://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/bysc/competitive/ontario-player-development-league/"

But this is what's being outputted right now:

"Test sentence for excerpt..."

This is how I'm calling it in my code: `$content = get_excerpt(320, 'content');` what I don't understand is if it's set at `320` it should grab all of this content, but it's not.

Here's the excerpt function:

```
function get_excerpt($limit, $source = null){

    if($source == "content" ? ($excerpt = get_the_content()) : ($excerpt = get_field('bio')));
        $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
        $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
        $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $limit);
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
        $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
        $excerpt = '<p>' . $excerpt . '...</p><div class="read-more"><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="bysc-btn-text bysc-btn-text-primary">Read More</a></div>';
    return $excerpt;
}
```

Why is the text being cut off early? Shouldn't it show it all?

Comment: It's not clear from your post -- did you hook up your `get_excerpt()` function with `add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'get_excerpt', 999 );`?  Also, you should add a personalized prefix to the function name `get_excerpt`, i.e. `darren_get_excerpt` to avoid naming collisions.

Comment: @DaveRomsey No I'm not using an `add_filter`. I'm using the `$content` I mentioned in my post inside my loop.

Comment: `strripos($excerpt, " ")` will always cut off the last word. Your function is ignoring UTF-8 characters, so it will break other things inevitably. :) See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11085/truncating-custom-fields/11089#11089) for a better version.

Comment: @fuxia interesting, I guess in the SO page I linked, the person who wrote the code made an error.